# ¿Por qué cuando compilo mi app y la instalo no se reproduce y se queda cargando el audio? r

Tags: flutter, dart, app

solo se queda cargando aquí **`CircularProgressIndicator()`**, he probado también otro paquetes para reproducir una transmisión de radio pero la mayoría no me funciona al crear el apk por que no emiten el sonido como sino cargara la url.

Este es el código:

```
child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Text("Science Friday"),
      Text("Science Friday and WNYC Studios"),
      StreamBuilder<FullAudioPlaybackState>(
        stream: _player.fullPlaybackStateStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final fullState = snapshot.data;
          final state = fullState?.state;
          final buffering = fullState?.buffering;
          return Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              if (state == AudioPlaybackState.connecting ||
                  buffering == true)
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  width: 64.0,
                  height: 64.0,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              else if (state == AudioPlaybackState.playing)
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
                  iconSize: 64.0,
                  onPressed: _player.pause,
                )
              else
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                  iconSize: 64.0,
                  onPressed: _player.play,
                ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
                iconSize: 64.0,
                onPressed: state == AudioPlaybackState.stopped ||
                        state == AudioPlaybackState.none
                    ? null
                    : _player.stop,
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
```

Comment: Puedes poner el código completo para poder ayudarte?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio2/example

Comment: uso solo ese ejemplo y me funciona en debug, pero cuando lo compilo el apk se queda cargando el CircularProgressIndicator()

Comment: PD. solo le cambio el link por uno de transmicion de radio

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas que pueden darte problemas, si te funciona en el debug pero te falla en el release puedes iniciar por verificar lo siguiente:

- Revisar las opciones de proguard, puede que este evitando que se ejecute la libreria
- Revisar la configuración de seguridad de red de Android si el enlace que estas usando no es HTTPS